# How to make a Following Character by using (anyword+'་') ,then make a next new line in WinForm using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to create custom word wrap with custom character. ie. I want to wrap the text using `.(dot)` character instead of [space](/questions/tagged/space).

I am doing a project on word wrapping in richTextBox using c# WinForm, therefore I need to work the  wordwrapping with (anyword+'་')together and then make the next new line because my problem is after every word wrapping '་' is coming at beginning/starting of the new line as shown in below example, '་' should come at every ending line

Suppose i have given origin string like: 
    རྒྱ་གར་ཚོང་པའི་ལྷན་ཚོགས་དངོས་སུ 
Once I used the wordwrap concept, Its coming like this 
     རྒྱ་གར་ཚོང་པའི // we assume that  this is first line

```
་ལྷན་ཚོགས་དངོས་སུ//this is second line and second line start with '་' so ending line should stay (anyword+'་')  before break the line and it should happen for linewise.
```

so to avoid this problem I thought of doing the concept of "following character". After so many googling and browsing I have found following threads that what am i looking for, but sadly they are using different tools and Platforms. I have try lots using these concept and achieve my project using C#(WinForm) but couldn't work. Therefore kindly share me your threads and help me out to do this my project using c# (WinForm). Your kind help meant me lots.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTajI2lWwgE
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/72d20e/canvas-text-wrapping-using-html-5/
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to add new line after every `.` than you need to replace the text i.e. `anyword. anyword` to `anyword.\r\nanyword` where the `\r\n` is the sequence for new line. but, it may create some problem like if you write M.B.B.S. then it may be like `M.\r\nB.\r\nB.\r\nS.\r\n`.

```
string str = "This is the simple text. Hello world".Replace(". ", ".\r\n");
```

OUTPUT:

```
This is the simple text.
Hello world.
```

**EDITED:**

```
int tmpIndex = 0;
int startIndex = 0;
int lastIndex = 0;
string sChar = ".";
string strText = richTextBox1.Text;

Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (tmpIndex > -1)
{
    lastIndex = tmpIndex;
    tmpIndex = strText.IndexOf(sChar, tmpIndex + 1);
    if (tmpIndex < 0)
        tmpIndex = strText.Length - 1;

    if (g.MeasureString(strText.Substring(startIndex, tmpIndex - startIndex), richTextBox1.Font).Width > richTextBox1.Width || tmpIndex == (strText.Length-1))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(strText.Substring(startIndex, lastIndex - startIndex));
        startIndex = lastIndex;                    
        if (tmpIndex == (strText.Length - 1))
            break;
        tmpIndex = lastIndex;
    }
}
richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Dear Shell, Thanks for the  help and actually this is the one i am looking for but for more specific i want to break the line after every '་'because we are using'་'after every single word in the above language like རྒྱ་གར་ཚོང་པའི so here we are using '་' instead of using "space" With many Thanks

Comment: Ohh.. You should clarify that in your question. BCoz u already got a close flag for unclear question. BTW, you can use Graphics.MeasureString() to check the length of string and then use IndexOf method to determine where is the `.` character is placed and just replace that character with new line. I will give u an full example later. I m lilbit hurry now.

Comment: Thank You @Shell. I have try with some code with my own.  string words=richTextBox1.text.split("་")
richTextBox1.text=words;
for(string srt=0; n<richTextBox1.length; n++)
{
string textline=richTextBox1+words[n]+"་";
string metrics=Graphics.MeasureString(textLine);
string textWidth=metrics.width;
if(textwidth>maxWidth){
context.filltext(richTextBox1,x,y);
richTextBox1.text=words[n]+"་";
} I knew that something is doing wrong. so kindly help me out.